# Text fields are not being filled in correctly in watir-webdriver

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I've recently decided to switch from using watir to using watir-webdriver for my test scripts. It's working great with the exception of this odd behavior. When it comes to a form with multiple text fields, such as a first name field and a last name field, it fills these in incorrectly. It usually fills in the first name and then fills in a letter or two of the last name, then jumps back to the first name field and appends the rest of the last name onto the first name.

An example would be first name/last name text fields. I write the script to fill in Jim for the first name and Johnson for the last name. When I run the script I will end up with Jimhnson for the first name and Jo for the last name. It's like it decides to jump back to the first name field in the middle of the last name field. This is something I never experienced using Watir and have searched all around for similar instances but have had no luck. Hopefully someone can help. Here's a sample of the code I'm using. I don't want to use "sleep 1", but have found it's the only thing that prevents this odd behavior.

```
 def fill_in_applicant_name(fName, lName)
  puts "Fills in the applicant first name"
  @@b.text_field(:id, "ApplicantFirstName").set(fName)

  #sleep 1

  puts "Fills in the applicant last name"
  @@b.text_field(:id, "ApplicantLastName").set(lName)
end
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to include the page html code with the problem and your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a sleep statement, it sounds like there's some AJAX or Javascript firing off after the text_field has been populated?  Since you are explicitly naming the text_fields that are being filled in there is really no other reason I can think of as to why the text should end up in one box.

The parentheses around your variable names are superfluous and not very Ruby-like.  They can be removed.

My approach to this method would use when_present in order to make sure that the text field is accessible.

```
def fill_in_applicant_name(first, last)
 @browser.text_field(:id, "First").when_present.set first
 @browser.text_field(:id, "Last").when_present.set last
end
```

Using other wait methods as necessary if you receive an error

```
Watir::Watir.until(30) { @browser.text_field(:id, "Last").visble? }
```

If that doesn't work can you post some code from the page you're testing to help us out?

Comment: Thanks Adam. Unfortunately I've tried when_present and other wait methods to see if that works and it still does it. The only fix so far has been to put the sleep statement in. It's not sleeping to wait for an element to appear but to pause the script between test fields. For some reason this works and the fields are filled in correctly.

Comment: Again, any chance we can see the page HTML?  Also your Ruby and Watir/Webdriver versions would be helpful.  Without some kind of AJAX or other dynamic element that would change the values of those text fields, I can't think of a reason why Ruby/Watir would cause this.

Comment: I found the answer and it's working so far. I had Firefox's native events set to "true". I changed that to "false" and it's working like a charm. I don't understand why but it's working correctly now.
'code'
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "conner"
profile.native_events = false
# set a variable to open a new browser
@@b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile 'code'

Comment: I apologize for the code in the above comment. I'm new to this and haven't figured out how to add code in a comment. Hope the above makes sense.

Comment: It does, Conner, but as you have 'resolved' the issue, I believe you might be working around an application issue.  You've resolved a symptom but most likely not the cause, because of the fact that this is not standard practice for other users.  What led you to this resolution?

Comment: This blog post by Alister Scott gave me the idea to set Native Events to false http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/16/disabling-native-events-when-using-firefox-with-webdriver/. I have my fingers crossed but it works well so far. I've spent a lot of time on this issue and I honestly can't think of a better solution than this. I guess I should put this solution as the answer but I want to give it some time to make sure.

Comment: I remember suffering from a problem like this when I originally swapped over from Watir to Watir-webdriver.  Unfortunately I remember this being the solution, too.

I know the fields in question (a basic registration form) had no special javascript firing during or after being filled, yet maybe 1 in 4 times it would switch fields in the middle of entering one of the fields.

With native events disabled, it completes the form hundreds of times without fail.

Comment: If the browser hasan auto-fill type option you might try disabling that and seeing if that takes care of the problem.  I'm not at all sure what the downside of disabling native events might be.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it has been a week or so of creating and running `watir-webdriver` tests with firefox's native events turned off. This has definitely been the answer to the problem. Since, turning native events off, I have not had a single occurrence of this unusual behavior. The tests/checks are running well and I only have one little issue. One of the app's pages a pop-up message appears and never disappears as you go on to the next pages. It is a little annoying, but it doesn't affect the tests in any way. Thanks everyone, for your input. Here's the code again for turning native events off.

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "webdriver"
profile.native_events = false
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Comment: Tip: don't use ```Profile.from_name```. This prevents your scripts from running on machines that don't have a "webdriver" profile. Instead, just do ```Profile.new```